# Ember service undefined when injected in route

Tags: ember.js, service, ember-data

When I inject a service in my route and I try to access it into the model or even in beforeModel, the service is not undefined but when I try to access a value of the service, everything is undefined.

my service looks like this

```
import Service from '@ember/service';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

export default Service.extend({
  session: service('session'),
  store: service(),

  load() {
    if (this.get('session.isAuthenticated')) {
      return this.get('store').queryRecord('user', { me: true }).then((user) => {
        this.set('user', user);
      });
    } else {
      return RSVP.resolve();
    }
  }
});
```

my route

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  session: service('session'),
  currentUser: service('currentUser'),

});
```

And I want to access it in my template for example, {{currentUser.user.email}} but it only works when I do this in a component.

Comment: Can you post your code? It's hard to say without guessing otherwise.

Comment: how are you accessing the service and the values of the service?

Comment: Sorry guys, I updated my post.

Comment: Code for the route too please

Comment: I updated my post, sorry

Comment: The template's context is the controller not the route, if you want access to `currentUser` in the template you have to inject the service in the controller.

Comment: Ok and can I access my service in the init method of the controller? I want to get a avlue of my service and set it as a property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the `currentUser` service from the controller, inject the service into the controller. The route will need to invoke `currentUser.load` method first in order to populate the `user` property on the service. Note that you may only want to invoke `currentUser.load` method once, so I suggest doing that in the application route.

**route.js**

```
import Route from '@ember/routing/route';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';
import RSVP from 'rsvp';

import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
  session: service('session'),
  currentUser: service('currentUser'),
  model() {
    // This will load the user data before rendering
    // This can also be done in the beforeModel
    return this.get('currentUser').load();
  }
});
```

**controller.js**

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service;

export default Controller.extend({
    currentUser: service()
});
```

template.hbs

```
Email: {{currentUser.user.email}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Garrick, this solved my issue.